# how to put a table and 3 buttons in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

Hi friends I want to layout 4 entities in one frame

1. A JTable
2. 3 buttons

For this I created a JFrame and put 2 JPanels inside that JFrame. One JPanel contains a scrollablePanel which holds a JTable. And another JPanel contains 3 JButtons.

I expected the output to be like below:

[image]

But My table is not visible anymore, only the buttons are visible.
Following is my code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class displayGui extends JFrame{
    private JPanel topPanel;
    private JPanel btnPanel;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public displayGui(JTable tbl){
        setTitle("Company Record Application");
        setSize(300,200);
        setBackground(Color.gray);


        topPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel = new JPanel();

        topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(topPanel);
        getContentPane().add(btnPanel);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tbl);
        topPanel.add(scrollPane,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton addButton = new JButton("ADD");
        JButton delButton = new JButton("DELETE");
        JButton saveButton = new JButton("SAVE");

        btnPanel.add(addButton);
        btnPanel.add(delButton);

    }
}
```

The code in my main method:

```
displayGui dg = new displayGui(table);
dg.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify a location for each panel on the frame...

Instead of...

```
getContentPane().add(topPanel);
getContentPane().add(btnPanel);
```

Try...

```
getContentPane().add(topPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
getContentPane().add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

**Side Note**

The `JFrame`s add method automatically redirects calls to it to the the `contentPane`, so, technically, you only need to do ...

```
add(topPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

**Updated**

I should also point out that the default layout manager for a `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`.  You can change this by simply calling `JFrame#setLayout`, but the result you're after is best meet with the `BorderLayout`...FYI

Comment: The reason for "*why you should provide direction constants in add method?*" is explained in [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) java document: *As a convenience, BorderLayout interprets the absence of a string specification, in the add method, the same as the constant CENTER*